# What's the correct way to render out html with a str_limit inside of a blade template?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have some HTML being rendered out inside of my blade template that looks like the following

```
{{str_limit($ticket->ticket_description), 300}}
```

And its printing out with HTML tags instead of formatting as I'd expect, so I think this is the way it should be but im seeing errors in php storm about requiring a semicolon.

```
{{!!str_limit($ticket->ticket_description), 300!!}}
```

So what is the correct way to render out HTML with str_limit?

Comment: `str_limit` takes two arguments. You've put the second argument outside the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Panic pointed out my typo here. This works now as expected.

{{!! str_limit($ticket->ticket_description, 300) !!}}